Python Replace XML Text with Escape Sequence
I have a third-party application that is parsing magic strings within an XML file, even though it should be treating them as character literals.  As an example, suppose my XML contained the following segment:
<element>Sentence containing magicString</element>

To prevent the third party application from parsing magicString as a command, I want to convert this xml fragment to:
<element>Sentence containing &#109;agicString</element>

How can I achieve this in Python, without doing a global find-replace (e.g., there may be elements named magicString that cannot be renamed or the XML is invalid)?  The following illustrates what I have attempted:
from xml.etree import ElementTree
xml = ElementTree.parse(xmlPath)
element = xml.find('.//grandparent/parent/element'):
element.text = '&#109;agicString'
xml.write(xmlPath)

The problem is that assigning to the Element.text property escapes the text, so the result in an XML file with the following contents:
<element>&amp;#109;agicString</element>


Why not to use XSLT for the task, and call it from Python?

Do you know how to do this where the XSLT doesn't undo the character escaping?  I can't figure that out, but XSLT would be a valid solution otherwise.

Here is XSLT based solution.
It will look just and only for text nodes containing a "magicString". XML elements are not affected.
Ampersand shall be always entitized as &amp; in the XML. Otherwise, XML would be not well-formed.
You can download Saxon Python XSLT 3.0 engine here: Python downloads
Saxon Home Edition (HE) is free of charge.
Input XML
<root>
    <magicString>Another sentence</magicString>
    <element>Sentence containing magicString</element>
    <city>Miami</city>
</root>

XSLT 3.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="findMe" select="'magicString'"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()[contains(., $findMe)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $findMe, concat('&amp;#109;', substring($findMe, 2, 100)))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<root>
  <magicString>Another sentence</magicString>
  <element>Sentence containing &amp;#109;agicString</element>
  <city>Miami</city>
</root>

Python
from saxonche import *

output_file = 'output.xml'

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    print(proc.version)
    try:
        xsltproc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
        document = proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name='input.xml')
        executable = xsltproc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file="process.xslt")

        output = executable.transform_to_string(xdm_node=document)

        with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(output.encode('utf-8'))

    except PySaxonApiError as err:
        print('Error during function call', err)

Here's a modified version of the XSLT that uses a different character (in this case &#178; (superscript 2)) and a character map to map that to the entity reference you wanted. You just need to use a character that won't exist already in your input so it doesn't accidentally get replaced.
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="magic"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:character-map name="magic">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#178;" string="&amp;#109;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    
    <xsl:param name="findMe" select="'magicString'"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()[contains(., $findMe)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $findMe, '&#178;'||substring($findMe, 2))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

This produces:
<root>
   <magicString>Another sentence</magicString>
   <element>Sentence containing &#109;agicString</element>
   <city>Miami</city>
</root>

Screenshot of Python/XSLT in PyCharm producing desired output:


This solution is still suffering from the same problem, and I can't figure out how to work around it either. I need the output to be <element>Sentence containing &#109;agicString</element>. The XSLT presented here is escaping the ampersand in the same way as what I initially tried.

As I already explained in the answer: "Ampersand shall be always entitized as & in the XML. Otherwise, XML would be not well-formed."

XML prohibited character literals: https://www.w3resource.com/xml/prohibited-character-literals.php

@JeffG - I added a modified XSLT to Yitzhak's answer that should do what you're asking. I figured that was better than creating a whole new answer. Yitzhak - if you prefer I'll add a different answer and revert yours to its original state.

Based on my reading of the XML standard, my XML is valid.  See section 4.1 Character and Entity References.  Seems like it is required to fully support character entities of the form &#\d+; and &#x[0-9A-Fa-f]+;.  However, that may only apply to entity references.

@DanielHaley, no worries. we are good.

This still isn't working for me, even with @DanielHaley's suggested edits.  I can either produce something that contains &amp;#109;agicString or the entities are expanded into magicString.  I cannot for the life of me determine how to fix this using XSLT.  Maybe it is a limitation of the Saxon Python tool?

There is no way around it: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp Please check "Entity References" section.

@JeffG - Using Yitzhak's Python and input XML along with my XSLT, I get the exact output you requested with &#109;agicString. I added a screenshot of it working in PyCharm.

I'm not certain what was causing it to not work for me,  but I verified that the proposed code and stylesheet do in fact produce exactly what I was asking for.  I was also able to simplify the python output to executable.transform_to_file(xdm_node=document, output_file=output_file).

I liked the solution from Yitzhak and Daniel.
Maybe a hack with saxutils can help you too ref:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

xml_ = """<element>Sentence containing magicString</element>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)
print('Origin:', root.text)

a = escape(f"{root.text}", {"magicString": "&#109;agicString"})
print('Escaped:', a)
root.text = a

with open("w_xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(root).decode().replace("&amp;","&")) 
    # <element>Sentence containing &#109;agicString</element>

Output:
Origin: Sentence containing magicString
Escaped: Sentence containing &#109;agicString

